# Handling Shared Library Dependencies with CMake and C++

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors

I have a c++ project that utilizes shared libraries, some of which have dependencies of their own.  However, I am being forced to include the header files for the shared library dependencies within my main.cpp file.  I'm assuming that this is an issue with how I have structured my project, but I'm not sure.

Project Structure:

```
- myproject
|-> foo1
  |-> include
    |-> foo1_stuff.hpp
  |-> src
    |-> main.cpp
  |-> build
  |-> CMakeLists.txt
|-> foo2
  |-> include
    |-> foo2_stuff.hpp
  |-> src
    |-> main.cpp
  |-> build
  |-> CMakeLists.txt
|-> lib
  |-> bar
    |-> include
      |-> bar.hpp
    |-> src
      |-> bar.cpp
  |-> bar_tool
    |-> include
      |-> bar_tool.hpp
    |-> src
      |-> bar_tool.cpp
  |-> CmakeLists.txt
```

foo1's main.cpp:

```
#include <bar_tool.hpp>

int main()
{
    bar_tool tool;
    tool.doStuff();

    return 0;
}
```

bar_tool.hpp:

```
#include <bar.hpp>

class bar_tool
{
public:
    bar_tool();
    ~bar_tool();
    int var;
    void doStuff();
};
```

bar_tool.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bar_tool.hpp>

bar_tool::bar_tool() : var(0) {}
bar_tool::~bar_tool() {}

void bar_tool::doStuff()
{
    std::cout << barFunction(var) << std::endl;
}
```

bar.cpp:

```
int barFunction(int value)
{
    return value + 2;
}
```

Foo1 CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(foo)

set(PROJECT_ROOT ~/myproject/)
set(
    CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_ROOT}/bin/
)

link_directories(
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib
)

include_directories(
    include
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar_tool/include
)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    bar_tool
)
```

Shared Libraries CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(myproject)

set(PROJECT_ROOT ~/myproject/)
set(
    CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/
)

link_directories(
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib
)

include_directories(
    include
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar/include
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar_tool/include
)

# bar library
set(LIB_NAME "bar")
file(GLOB LIB_SRC "${LIB_NAME}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_SRC})

# bar_tool library
set(LIB_NAME "bar_tool")
file(GLOB LIB_SRC "${LIB_NAME}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_SRC})
target_link_libraries(
    ${LIB_NAME}
        bar
)
```

I would expect that using the compiled bar_tool shared library (`libbar_tool.so`) would not require having to include `bar.hpp` in the `include_directories` section of foo1's CMakeLists.  However, I get following error if I don't:

```
In file included from /home/mrd/Development/compile_test/foo/src/main.cpp:1:0:
/home/mrd/Development/compile_test/lib/bar_tool/include/bar_tool.hpp:1:10: fatal error: bar.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <bar.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Am I not using shared libraries or CMake (or both) correctly?

**FIX:**

**UPDATED** Shared Libraries CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(myproject)

set(PROJECT_ROOT ~/myproject/)
set(
    CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/
)

# bar library
set(LIB_NAME "bar")
file(GLOB LIB_SRC "${LIB_NAME}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_SRC})
target_include_directories(
    ${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar/include
)

# bar_tool library
set(LIB_NAME "bar_tool")
file(GLOB LIB_SRC "${LIB_NAME}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_SRC})
target_include_directories(
    ${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar_tool/include
)
target_link_libraries(
    ${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
    bar
)
```

*Not sure if this had any effect, but I changed this also:*

**UPDATED** Foo1 CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(foo)

set(PROJECT_ROOT /home/mrd/Development/compile_test)
set(
    CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_ROOT}/bin/
)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/ bin)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    bar_tool
)
```

Any other suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Shared Libraries `CMakeLists.txt` file, consider adding the [`PUBLIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents) keyword to ensure that the transitive dependencies (i.e. the `bar` library) can be propagated to the final target. Also, modern CMake encourages the use of [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) instead of `include_directories()`. Similarly, you should add the `PUBLIC` keyword here also:

```
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar/include
)
target_include_directories(bar_tool PUBLIC
    ${PROJECT_ROOT}/lib/bar_tool/include
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
        bar
)
```

Comment: I added `PUBLIC` as shown, but this did not fix the problem

Comment: @user3489620 Updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I updated the post to show these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the compiled library you do not need to add the paths of the source files.
All the function calls, external variable access etc will be linked to this precompiled library.

Whereas when you include header file this is not the case.
Make creates a list of dependencies before compilation where it tries to locate all the headers.
Hence paths of all the headers which are included directly or indirectly must be provided.

Comment: Could you please explain what would need to change in order to use the precompiled library without including the header file?